# How Can I Pull data out of a SharePoint list from embedded code on the same SharePoint Domain Using SPservices and Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, spservices

I am trying to pull data from a column in a list. The list is in the same domain as the page that I have embedded code in.

Here is the code, I have removed several of the functions that do not have anything to do with the code so if the HTML looks funny that is why.

Essentially, I am doing a SPServices call against the list "Master List" and then passing the results into an array. Once I have them in an array I then use the each function of JQuery to append them to a div.

I'm not seeing the new tags in the DIV, which leads me to believe I've messed something up. This is my first time using the SPServices library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>

<div id="data">

    <form id="vendorFormMain" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
            <legend>Search Vendors</legend>
            <label for="searchVendors" id='searchVendors" value="Search Vendors'>Search Vendors</label>
            <select id="searchVendors">
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>


    <form id="categoriesForm" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <fieldset id="categoriesSearch" >
            <legend>Categories</legend>
            <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
                <legend> Search Categories</legend>
                <label for="categories" id="categoriesLabel">Select Category</label>
                <select id="categories" style="padding-bottom: 5px;" >
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
                <legend> Search Vendors</legend>
                <label for="vendors" id="vendorLabel">Select Vendor</label>
                <select id="vendors" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form id="vendorsData" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
            <legend>Vendors</legend>
            <label for="contactCompany" style="width: 500px; clear: both;"> Company Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="contactCompany" style="width: 100%; clear: both;" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
            <label for="contactName" style="width: 500px; clear: both;"> Contact Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="contactName" style="width: 100%; clear: both;" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
            <label for="contactNumber" style="width: 500px; clear: both;"> Contact Number: </label>
            <input type="text" id="contactNumber" style="width: 100%; clear: both;" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
            <label for="contactEmail" style="width: 500px; clear: both;"> Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="contactEmail" style="width: 100%; clear: both;" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="resultarea">
    <p><strong>TEST</strong></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        getCompanies();
    });


    function getCompanies() {
        // The Web Service method I am calling to read list items is 'GetListItems' 
        var method = "GetListItems";

        //The name of the List
        var list = "Master List";

        //Setting the fields I want to read from
        var fieldsToRead ="<ViewFields>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Company' />" +
                            "</ViewFields>";

        //Set the query to orderby the Company field
        var query = "<Query>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" + 
                            "<FieldRef Name='Company'/>" +
                        "</OrderBy>" +
                    "</Query>";

        //Here is my SPServices Call. I use the fields above for the call.
        $().SPServices({
            operation: method,
            async: false, 
            listName: list,
            CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
            CAMLQuery: query,

            // Create a delegate with a callback that allows me to read values and write to array.
            completefunc: Function.createDelegate(this, window.callback)
        });
        window.callback = function (xData, status) {
            //Create a new array titled "aCompanies" to hold company data
            var aCompanies = new Array();
            //Use SPFilterNode to parse through each node and push the node to the array
            jQuery(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {           
                aCompanies.push(jQuery(this).attr('Company'));
            });
            //Use Jquery Each method to loop through the array "companies"
            jQuery.each(aCompanies, function (i, val) {
                // add the results of the array to the display here div
                $("#resultarea").append("<p>" + val + "</p>");
            });
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working. I found the SP.JS file in the Layout folder of Sharepoint. With this I was able to Google about Sharepoint
s REST API with OData at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx and about OData Query parameters at http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#SelectSystemQueryOption . This allowed me to go and make my AJAX calls.

I was able to build out the AJAX call using a straight GET method and was then able to take the resulting data and parse it out using the JQuery Each function. I then was able to append this to my HTML.

The final code is below:

```
<div id="data">

    <form id="vendorFormMain" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
            <legend>Search Vendors</legend>
            <label for="searchVendors" id='searchVendors" value="Search Vendors'>Search Vendors</label>
            <select id="searchVendors">
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>


    <form id="categoriesForm" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <fieldset id="categoriesSearch" >
            <legend>Categories</legend>
            <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
                <legend> Search Categories</legend>
                <label for="categories" id="categoriesLabel">Select Category</label>
                <select id="categories" style="padding-bottom: 5px;" >
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
                <legend> Search Vendors</legend>
                <label for="vendors" id="vendorLabel">Select Vendor</label>
                <select id="vendors" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form id="vendorsData" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
            <legend>Vendors</legend>
            <label for="contactCompany" style="width: 500px; clear: both;"> Company Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="contactCompany" style="width: 100%; clear: both;" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
            <label for="contactName" style="width: 500px; clear: both;"> Contact Name:  </label>
            <input type="text" id="contactName" style="width: 100%; clear: both;" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
            <label for="contactNumber" style="width: 500px; clear: both;"> Contact Number: < </label>
            <input type="text" id="contactNumber" style="width: 100%; clear: both;" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
            <label for="contactEmail" style="width: 500px; clear: both;"> Email: </label>
            <input type="text" id="contactEmail" style="width: 100%; clear: both;" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        getCategories();
        getVendorsSearch();
    });

    function getVendorsSearch() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://{main_url_here}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Master List')/items",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#searchVendors").prepend('<option value="-1">-Select Vendor-</option>')
                    .val('-1');
                $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                    $("#searchVendors").append('<option value=' + item.Company + '>' + item.Company + '</option>');
                });
                $("#searchVendors").val("");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error getVendorsSearch");
            }
        });
    };

    function getCategories() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://{main_url_here}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Master List')/items",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#categories").prepend('<option value="-1">-Select Category-</option>')
                    .val('-1');
                $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                    $("#categories").append('<option value="' + item.Product_x0020_Focus + '">' + item.Product_x0020_Focus + '</option>');
                });
                $("#categories").val("");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error getCategories");
            }
        });
    };

    $("#categories").change(function populateVendors() {
        var categoryType = $("#categories option:selected").val();
        getVendors(categoryType);
    });

    function getVendors(categoryType) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://{main_url_here}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Master List')/items?$filter=Product_x0020_Focus eq '" + categoryType + "'",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#vendors").empty();
                $("#vendors").prepend('<option value="-1">-Select Vendor-</option>')
                    .val('-1');
                $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                    $("#vendors").append('<option value="' + item.Company + '">' + item.Company + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error getVendors");
                alert(categoryType);
                alert(url);
            }
        });
    };


    $("#vendors").change(function displayVendorData() {
        var companyName = $("#vendors option:selected").val();
        getVendorData(companyName);
    });

    $("#searchVendors").change(function displaySearchVendorData() {
        var companyName = $("#searchVendors option:selected").val();
        getVendorData(companyName);
    });

    function getVendorData(companyName) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://{main_url_here}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Master List')/items?$filter=Company eq '" + companyName + "'",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                    $("#contactCompany").val(item.Company);
                    $("#contactName").val(item.Contact_x0020_Name);
                    $("#contactNumber").val(item.Contact_x0020_Cell);
                    $("#contactEmail").val(item.Contact_x0020_E_x002d_Mail);
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error getVendorData");
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```